How can I enable the fields of Associated Automation in Test Case of Azure devops?
I have the Associated Automation tab, but all the fields are disabled currently. How can I enable it? Please help me with this.

I have tried all sorts of combinations, but nothing worked. Please help me with steps like enabling it for all my Test cases.

Hi , welcome to stack overflow. The Associated Automation field are read only in web portal . You can check my answer to associate automated tests with test cases in Visual Studio. Please let me know if you have more questions.

Glad to hear that my answer can help you. Happy coding!

The fields of Associated Automation in Test Case are used to track the Automated test information. The fields are read-only in the web portal but can be updated through Test Explorer in Visual Studio. So you should associate automated tests with test cases in Visual Studio, then the fields will be auto filled with the information of the test.
You can refer the steps to associate your test here.
My test screenshots:



